# salesforce wave analytics

Tags: einstein-analytics, data-set

How can we add(doing summation) of values in dataset compare table, row wise? Currently we have ability to add/subtract/multiply values columns wise but I need summation of values row wise.

[image]

One more points is, how can we add an extra column at the bottom(just below On Hold row)?

Answer (score 0):

Wave Analytics provides this facility for displaying the `summary`.

> Just that it will be visible at the top of the table and not at the
>   bottom.

See below image, highlighted `button` will allow you to `summarize` the data.

[image]

So, when you click this, `summary of rows` would be available at the **top** of the table.

See below image, showing the summary:

[image]

See if this helps!